# How to get just one of the same record in foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I have this query to return the categories a user posted in

```
$this['items'] = Advert::with('cats')->where('user_id', $slug)->get();
```

and in twig i have

```
{% for item in items %}


{{ item.cats.cat_title }}<br>

{% endfor %}
```

It is returned this way

> Agro-Products and Commodity Agro-Products and Commodity Auto Parts and Accessories Agro-Products and Commodity Agro-Products and Commodity Agro-Products and Commodity Agro-Products and Commodity Agro-Products and Commodity Agro-Products and Commodity Men's Clothing Men's Clothing

Is there a way to get just one of the same record returned? `first()` does not do it

Comment: you can try `$this['items'] = Advert::with('cats')->where('user_id', $slug)->distinct('column_name')->get();`  to eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$this['items'] = Advert::select('cat_id')
                   ->with('cats')
                   ->groupby('cat_id')
                   ->where('user_id', $slug)
                  ->get();

// replace `cat_id` with the category id column
```